# JTreeTable model updating

Tags: swing, jtable, jtree, jtreetable

I'm following the example of JTreeTable filesystem2 taken from the sun site http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/treetable2/index.html#updating_the 
My problem is that I can't update my model (and then my JTreeTable)...
In fact I create my model, I pass it to the JTreeTable and all work fine...but  I need to modify the model...
I've yet answer a similar question, but now I've changed my code, without find a solution.

The problem is when and how I have to call the method fireTreeNodesChanged()...in the example above is used the method getPath() to retrieve information about the root node...but this is a method of File class..not my case...

Does anyone have a link to a simple code which shows how create a TreeTabelModel (with objects as nodes) and how update it?

Comment: dont quite understand what exactly is the problem. Whatever, note that the TreeTableModel _is-a_ TreeModel. So you can search for examples/tutorials about implemnting dynamic TreeModel/-implementations and do it similarly. BTW, SwingX has a JXTreeTable that's much improved compared to that oldish example above :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`FileBrowser`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui) is a good example of modeling a hierarchical file system as a tree. While its `TreeModel` is implemented using `DefaultTreeModel`, an alternative [`FileTreeModel`](http://java.dzone.com/news/taking-new-swing-tree-table-a-) is shown [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui/4447#4447). As mentioned in [*How to Use Trees: Creating a Data Model*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#data) "the `TreeModel` interface accepts any kind of object as a tree node."